# All connection default to .onion.to Why cant I get just .onion

Tags: tails, onion-routing

I am now running tails. The latest version.

Before Xmas I could browse .onion sites easily just by downloading the tor browser on to my linux system. Since the New Year, I have found some sites are not available and I get a banner across the top of the pages of those sites which are available, from Tor2web.

Research tells me that tor2web is a web proxy service for tor. I didn't install it, or ask for it and it is the same problem on all devices I use on my network. Can I assume that my ISP is now directing tor traffic through Tor2web?

Research also suggests there are many other proxy sites for tor out there and they convert my .onion addresses to cached .onion.to addresses (or a similar extension). Research suggests that I should the remove the extra .to extension and a direct connection can be made. That didn't work for me.

I have used bridges with obfs4 and still get to onion.to sites. I have now installed Tails (rather than just the tor browser) with bridges and obfs4 and I  still cannot get through to .onion sites, I can only get onion.to sites. Does anyone have any more ideas of what is going on and how to solve it, that is, to get a direct Tor connection to .onion sites?

I have scoured for answers to this, but can't find any. Let me know if you can direct me to a comprehensive solution.

Thanks

Comment: Once the TBB is on a `.onion.to` site, it stays on these. Try again and make sure that the starting point is, f.ex. http://ahmia.fi

Comment: `Can I assume that my ISP is now directing tor traffic through Tor2web?` Would be highly unlikely unless tails has some problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a tails issue, this happens because you go on the links which then is passed trough the tor2web service.

The links you use through there has .to appended to the link.
So duckduckgo's hidden service is originally like this : http://3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion/ , but through tor2web it looks like http://3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion.to/

So what you can do is to remove the .to from the url and go straight to the regular hidden service, and edit any bookmarks you have stored with .to.

Comment: @PhillVS mentioned that `research suggests that I should the remove the extra .to extension and a direct connection can be made. That didn't work for me. `

Comment: We need more info. Give us example links, show log outputs. There is a reason why things does not work, and to find it we need more info so that we can test and confirm.